# How to prevent automatic resizing of MaterialAlertDialogBuilder height when the keyboard is open?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-textinputlayout, material-dialog

I have built a custom dialog with MaterialAlertDialogBuilder. The dialog has 2 TextInputLayouts. The problem is when I try to write something in the TextInputEditText and when the keyboard is visible, the MaterialAlertDialogBuilder shrinks in height.

**In XML code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:viewBindingIgnore="true">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="দোয়া"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:shapeAppearance="@style/ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent"
        tools:viewBindingIgnore="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/doarName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:hint="দৈনিক কতবার পাঠ করবেন?"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:shapeAppearance="@style/ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent"
        tools:viewBindingIgnore="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**In Kotlin:**

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this@TosbiActivity).setView(view).setTitle("দোয়া যুক্ত করুন")
                .setPositiveButton("Apply") { dialog, _ ->

                    /*
                    ......
                     */

                    dialog.dismiss()
                }.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }.show()
```

**The output of ths code:**

(when the keyboard is hidden)

[image: (when the keyboard is hidden).]

(when the keyboard is visible)

[image: (When the keyboard is visible)]

**What am I tried?**

I checked by adding the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>` and `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` codes in
activity tag of the manifest, but it doesn't work.
And also I searched or asked about this on the internet + ChatGPT AI but got no correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the mentioned problem the dialog is created using [MaterialAlertDialogBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/dialog/MaterialAlertDialogBuilder). But the problem is that when the dialog is shown on a small screen, clicking on the input field is resizing the dialog box. Below is a simple way to solve this problem.

The problem can be solved in two ways.

**Alert Dialog Builder Code:**

```
 val dialog = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
            .setView(View.inflate(this,R.layout.dialog, null))
            .setTitle("দোয়া যুক্ত করুন")
            .setPositiveButton("Apply") { d, _ ->
                d.dismiss()
            }.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { d, _ ->
                d.dismiss()
            }.create()
```

**The first one:**

```
dialog.window?.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN)
```

**The second:**

```
dialog.window?.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
```

Adding either [WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN) or [WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS) to the constant will hopefully work.

> Note: window.addFlage must be set before showing the dialog

**The code snippet:**

```
  val dialog = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
                    .setView(View.inflate(this,R.layout.dialog, null))
                    .setTitle("দোয়া যুক্ত করুন")
                    .setPositiveButton("Apply") { d, _ ->
                        d.dismiss()
                    }.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { d, _ ->
                        d.dismiss()
                    }.create()

        
   dialog.window?.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN)
   dialog.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

After doing a lot of research, I figured out the cause of the problem.

The problem was due to the screen size of the device. I have checked on a device with a bigger screen size than my device, the problem does not occur.

To avoid this problem: `AlertDialog.Builder` can be used instead of `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` or you can solve the problem by adding this code to your `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`.

```
.window?.setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
                )
```

**The complete code will look like this:**

```
val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_doa, null)

            MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this@TosbiActivity).setView(view).setTitle("দোয়া যুক্ত করুন")
                .setPositiveButton("Apply") { dialog, _ ->

                    /*
                    ......
                     */

                    dialog.dismiss()
                }.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }.show().window?.setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the screen size of your device.
If you test the app on a device with a larger screen size, the issue won't occur.

**My recommendation is: Use `AlertDialog.Builder` instead of `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`.**

also you can create an issue on '**material-components-android**' repo in [github](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android), so they can fix it .
Until they fix it use **AlertDialog.Builder**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've crated an issue on GitHub.
Issue link: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/4039

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this solution on all screen sizes but I wrap whole layout inside a `ScrollView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        tools:viewBindingIgnore="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="দোয়া"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:shapeAppearance="@style/ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent"
            tools:viewBindingIgnore="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/doarName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:hint="দৈনিক কতবার পাঠ করবেন?"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:shapeAppearance="@style/ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent"
            tools:viewBindingIgnore="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: As an alternative system I continue to work like this (wrapping the entire code in a scrollview).