# how to make an EditText fully visible when opening the soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

In my Android activity, I have an EditText with other layouts before and after.
When I click in the EditText, the soft keyboard is open and the view is scrolled just enough so that I can see the cursor.

This seems to be the default behavior.

But I would like that the EditText is FULLY visible (I have a border around it).

How can I do that?

My current code:

manifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    ...
```

layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minHeight="300dp"
        android:background="#bbbbbb"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/notes"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linear1"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:minLines="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:background="#bbbbbb"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/notes"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

With closed keyboard:

[image]

With open keyboard (current behavior): the EditText is truncated

[image]

Expected behavior:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77411599/6576302

Answer (score 2):

Changes to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivityName"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" /> //you can omit stateHidden if you want your keyboard to auto focus your edit text view when you navigate to your activity
```

Changes to `your_activity_name_activity.xml`:

Keep everything as it is and encapsulate the Constraint Layout into this ScrollView and make the ScrollView your root.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:fillViewport="true"> 

                  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
                    ....
                  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Lastly add these flags to your edittext:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        ...
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionDone"/>
```

Comment: I tried your proposal, but the result is the same: the EditText is only partially displayed when the keyboard is open (the minimum so that the cursor is visible.

Comment: Are you perhaps not allowing configuration changes for your project or activity? You should delete `android:configChanges=` from your manifest

Answer (score 0):

set your activity windowSoftInput mode to adjustResize in manifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

then wrap your content with a scrollview

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Update: this works for me

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minHeight="300dp"
            android:background="#bbbbbb"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/notes"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linear1"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:minLines="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:background="#bbbbbb"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/notes" />
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I have already tried your answer, but it did not work. maybe because I inserted the scrollview in a wrong way.
Could you please give more details on where you add the scrollview ?

Comment: Thanks for the update. There is an issue with the proposed code: A scroll view can have only one child. There is a warning in the IDE (and no preview), plus the  app crashes when launching it. 
I tried to move the ScrollView around the ConstraintLayout. It is a bit better in that when the keyboard is open, it is possible to scroll to fully view the EditText.
But the EditText is not fully displayed by default when the keyboard opens

Answer (score 0):

Implement custom input behavior by using next API: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputConnection

Comment: It looks way too much complex for my "simple" need.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that an EditText is fully visible when the soft keyboard is open, you can adjust your layout and use the android:windowSoftInputMode attribute in your AndroidManifest.xml file.
step-by-step guide:

**1.Place your EditText inside a ScrollView**

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        
        <!-- Your other views here -->
        
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        
        <!-- Your other views here -->
        
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**2. Change in Manifest File**

In your AndroidManifest.xml, set the android:windowSoftInputMode attribute to adjustResize or adjustPan for the activity containing the layout. adjustResize will resize your activity's layout to ensure the EditText remains visible when the keyboard opens, while adjustPan will pan the entire layout to make the focused EditText visible.

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan">
    <!-- Other activity configurations -->
</activity>
```

Hope This will help you

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is similar to previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try 1** : android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

**Try 2** : AppCompatEditText is placed within a ScrollView or NestedScrollView

As you told these are not working there is one more solution

**Try 3**:
You use app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" to anchor bottom of the your layout to bottom of parent when adjusting layout to the keyboard

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Other views or constraints -->

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <!-- Other views or constraints -->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

By implementing this, AppCompatEditText should remain fully shown to screen when the soft keyboard is opened providing a better user experience. Adjusting the layout ensures that AppCompatEditText not covered by keyboard, allowing users to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".PasswordReset.PasswordResetActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:minHeight="300dp"
                android:background="#bbbbbb"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:minHeight="300dp"
                android:background="#bbbbbb"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:minHeight="300dp"
                android:background="#bbbbbb"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/notes"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linear1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:maxLines="10"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:minHeight="300dp"
                android:background="#bbbbbb"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:minHeight="300dp"
                android:background="#bbbbbb"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:minHeight="50dp"
                android:background="#bbbbbb"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/notes"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The above code is what i did to give you the best possible solution, the XML code you have provided contains a lot of design issues, for example you have forcefully used linear layout with a height of 300dp without containing any child within it, this does not allow the UI to perform optimally, secondly you have used min lines = 10 which again is hampering the UI, thirdly, how the soft input behaves is, it basically will push the UI only that much under which the user can comfortably view what is being typed. therefor if you intend to make your edit text occupy more space or have a height greater than the default height the ui is unable to push it completely upward. In short what you are trying to achieve is possible but not the way you have designed the layout of your UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the insets API to listen to window changes to know if the keyboard is shown/hidden, and adjust a bottom margin to the root layout that equals to the height of the keyboard if it's shown (the system bottom bar height can be considered as well).

But, that requires a `ScrollView` as a root layout to make the layout scroll-able in order to show your layout bottom part when the keyboard is shown.

Also, you have to keep the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` as you already do.

In activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val root = findViewById<ScrollView>(R.id.root)

        // Apply window inset listener
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(window.decorView.rootView) { v: View, insets: WindowInsetsCompat ->
            // check if the keyboard is shown
            val keyboardVisible = insets.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
            // Get bottom system bar height
            val systemBarsHeight = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars()).bottom
            // Get keyboard height
            val keyboardHeight = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()).bottom
            // Apply bottom margin to the root view (ScrollView)
            val params =
                root.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams
            params.bottomMargin = if (keyboardVisible) systemBarsHeight + keyboardHeight else 0
            root.layoutParams = params
            ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets(v, insets)
        }

    }
}
```

And update the layout with the root `ScrollView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#bbbbbb"
            android:minHeight="300dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/notes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:minLines="10"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linear1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#bbbbbb"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/notes" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Preview:

[image]